# How can I write with a translator's dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is how my program is structured:

There is an n in the first line of the input that indicates the number of words in the translation dictionary. Each of the next n lines contains four words, the second to fourth words being the translation of the first word. Each word is translated into three different languages. The second word is the English translation, the third word is the French translation, and the fourth word is the German translation of the first word. The last line contains a sentence that needs to be translated from one of the English, French or German languages ​​into the first word. A sentence consists of several words separated by a space.

input:

```
4
man I je ich

kheili very très sehr

alaghemand interested intéressé interessiert 

barnamenevisi programming laprogrammation Programmierung

I am very interested in programming
```

Correct output:

```
man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
```

my code:

```
tedad = int(input())
d = dict(input().split(' ') for i in range(tedad))
c = ''
car = input().split(' ')

for x in car:
    if x in d:
        c+= ' '+d[x]

    else:
        c+=' '+x


print(c.strip())
```

My code has a problem and shows a wrong output. Please help me to correct the code and display it according to the sample output.

Comment: Translating from one language to another is not as simple as just writing a dictionary mapping words to their one of the possible meanings in an alternate language. So, your way of approaching the problem will not give correct results all the time. Sometimes, it may work but not always. For reference, even Google Translate does not show 100% correct results and has subtle deviations from the language in question. There is just too much to consider than what can be handled by a simple 1 to 1 mapping of words across languages.

Comment: you say you get an other output, but `dict(input().split(' ') for i in range(tedad))` is not compatible with the inputs you give (not two words per line), so the only possible output is an error

Comment: Your opinion is completely wrong
Surely if you read my question carefully, you will understand

Comment: If possible, please write my bug in the answer field, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict(input().split(' ') for i in range(tedad))` is not compatible with the inputs you give with not 2 words per line

One way can be from your code :

```
tedad = int(input())
d = {}
for i in range(tedad):
    l = input().split()
    for x in l[1:]:
        d[x] = l[0]

c = ''
car = input().split()

for x in car:
    c += ' ' + (d.get(x) or x)

print(c[1:])
```

having that in the file *p.py* and the input in *i* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat i
4
man I je ich
kheili very très sehr
alaghemand interested intéressé interessiert 
barnamenevisi programming laprogrammation Programmierung
I am very interested in programming
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py < i
man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is absolutely correct